# Is it possible to dump a certain range of variant into the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variant like these

```
var = sheet1.Range("A1:P3600").Value
```

I have done some operarions and pushed the unwanted rows to the top in the variant. Now I have to copy the var variant to the other sheet from a certain range.

```
sheet1.range("A3444:P" & i).value = var(range(cells(r,"A").cells(l,"P"))
```

that is say var(350 to end of var) should be copied to the other sheet. Is it possible ? can we do like that ?

Comment: instead of pushing the unwanted rows to the top, you'd probably better delete them or copy only the wanted rows to another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to dump the reduced array to a second array, then the second array to your range

The code below makes a variant array with 3600 rows by 16 columns (ie A:P), data is dumped into the array for sample data *(note you already have this array as Var)*, then a variable is used as a marker to reduce the array to a second array, the second array is then written to the range.

*Updated to match your exact data locations. In your case you have Var1 already (your Var), so you just need the second portion of the code that starts at `lngStop = 350` and make my code `Var1` references `Var`*

```
Sub TestME()
Dim Var1
Dim Var2
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long
Dim lngCnt3 As Long
Dim lngCnt4 As Long
Dim lngStop As Long
Var1 = Sheet1.Range([a1], [p3600]).Value2
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(Var1, 1)
    For lngCnt2 = 1 To 16
        Var1(lngCnt, lngCnt2) = "I am row " & lngCnt & " column " & lngCnt2
    Next lngCnt2
Next lngCnt
lngStop = 350
ReDim Var2(1 To UBound(Var1, 1) - lngStop + 1, 1 To UBound(Var1, 2))
For lngCnt3 = lngStop To UBound(Var1, 1)
    For lngCnt4 = 1 To UBound(Var1, 2)
        Var2(lngCnt3 - lngStop + 1, lngCnt4) = Var1(lngCnt3, lngCnt4)
    Next lngCnt4
Next lngCnt3
Sheet1.[a3444].Resize(UBound(Var2, 1), UBound(Var2, 2)).Value2 = Var2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* slap only a portion of your array onto the sheet, but only if that portion is at the top left of your array, i.e. only the *first* `n` columns and the *first* `m` rows. There is no straightforward way of slapping the the *last* `n` columns and the *last* `m` rows. In this case, you have to resort to transferring stuff to a second, smaller array, and then dump that onto the sheet, as in @brettdj's answer -- this works fine, but it's a bit roundabout and too much coding for my taste.

Instead, if you could push your "unwanted rows" down to the bottom of your array, then it would be a one-liner to slap the top rows of that array onto a sheet (omitting the last 350).

Here's an example where a 4 x 3 array is read in, and only the top-left 3 x 2 is slapped back onto the sheet. The secret is to make the target range smaller than the entire array.

```
Dim v
v = Range("A2:C5")
Range("E2:F4") = v
```

Comment: I disagree (in good humour) as I think asking someone to retrofit their existing code to sort to the bottom is a significant detour thats trumps my little traffic light (the actual code doing the work in my solution is 10 or so lines). But more so this approach offers no flexibility, it works for only one occasion once further code has been added to move rows, whereas my code can readily be adapted to trim both top and bottom, every third row etc.

Comment: Sure, yours is definitely more flexible, which is a big plus. Mine is cleaner, at least I think so. I guess it's a matter of taste!