# Copy a complete row of one var to other var

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variant like these

```
 ranging from var(1,42) to var(4000,42)
```

I have done some operations based on the requirement and filled the 42nd column of var with 0's and 1's. Now I have to import only those rows of var to the sheet that has 1 in its 42 nd column. These is what i have coded

```
t=1
For i = 1 to 4000
      If var(i,42) = 1  Then
         For k = 1 to 41
           var2(t,k) = var(i,k)
         Next k
         t = t + 1
      End If
Next i
```

What I think is to copy the needed rows from one var to other new_var,Im using looping something  like these

```
for k = 1 to 41 ' the inner loop
```

But people here says looping is time consuming. They even say its a bad style of writing code but I did not find a better way to copy one var to other var, I mean only the needed rows.Say suppose I have to copy the 30th row contents of one var to other var, Then Im using looping to copy from 1 to 41 the column contents, but is there something like copying the entire row of var to the other var?

Comment: I don't think anyone ever said that traversing (looping through) an array is slow! On the contrary, it's fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niko,

It is slow to loop *ranges* - looping *variant arrays* is exteremely fast. And it is certainly not bad code!

Your approach is fine.

So the same approach as my solution in [Is it possible to dump a certain range of variant into the sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631965/is-it-possible-to-dump-a-certain-range-of-variant-into-the-sheet) is fine for you to use. It writes 50,000 cells or so in to a second array, then dumps it to a sheet in less than a second

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> is there something like copying the entire row of var to the other var? [presumably in a single command]

The answer is: no, there isn't. Your approach is the only one I know of.

Comment: +1 Thanks for confirming my approach is the only one you know too